# How to convert buffer object to image in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I just tried to add image as buffer to mongodb and  tried to convert back to image.
In ejs, it worked fine.

`src="data:image/png;base64,<%=project.image1.toString('base64')%>"`

This is the code i used in ejs.

But when i tried to append this to an element through pure js, it shows error

```
$('#two').prepend($('<img>',{id:'theImg2',src:`data:image/png;base64,${ selected[0].image2.data.toString('base64')}`}))
```

This is the code i used in pure js.
[image: Image Buffer]

This is the object i consoled in js.

[image: Error that i am getting]

This is the error!

Thank you!

Comment: What error, you're not showing it.

Comment: oh, sorry. Now edited.

Comment: Where is: `image2.data` coming from?

Comment: Fetching data from MongoDB with nodejs and passed to javascript using ejs. Then trying to append image after filtering.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no `.toString('base64')` in JavaScript, that exists in Node.js Buffers, so you're just calling `.toString` on an `Object`, which will indeed output: `[Object Object]` which is what you're getting.

The equivalent of Node.js `buffer.toString('base64')` would be:

```
function toBase64(arr) {
   //arr = new Uint8Array(arr) if it's an ArrayBuffer
   return btoa(
      arr.reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
   );
}

$('#two').prepend($('<img>',{id:'theImg2',src:`data:image/png;base64,${toBase64( selected[0].image2.data)}`}))
```